# will setting CBCentralManager to nil lose connection?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

I wonder if setting my `CBCentralManager`-instance to `nil` result in loss of connection to devices, do I need a "live" CBCentralManager to be able to keep the connection alive?

I currently have a manager for scanning and connecting to new devices in a `Viewcontroller` pushed over the default `ViewController` with a NavigationController. The problem occur when I am done with the connection, I press the back button and my connection is lost according to the bluetooth indicator in the top statusbar, but if i inspect the `CBPeripheral` it still has the status of `_isConnected==YES`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it won't. What you do with your pointer isn't relevant for the others in this case.
Without `ARC`, this has no effect at all (in no case). With `ARC`, it might trigger a release call. But even that isn't relevant to the devices.

Comment: Thank you, will have to search for the error elsewhere then. a.k.a. rollback to my working code.